# Upgrade to 16.04 failed

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, package-management, updates

I was updating to 16.04 from 14.04, was getting occasional warnings & errors. Then I got a string of same messages, saying ...error: broken pipe. I tried rebooting, now I just get a terminal but don't know the commands to resume. Not all packages had fully downloaded. I am using the 12.04 CD to get online to type this message.

Answer (score 0):

If you can get to a terminal and have networking (?), many times you can repair a failed upgrade with:

```
 sudo apt-get -f install
```

then...

```
sudo apt full-upgrade
```

After those have run, do the usual *apt update* and *apt full-upgrade* again (with sudo) and see if there are any more errors.

If the problem is the windowing system, you can sometimes remedy that by just reinstalling the window manager you use with --reinstall option, eg like:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome
```

(I had this happen with a recent VMWare image and it was a bit of a pain to get working again, make sure you check permissions in your home directory if you have to do this...)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56676/discussion-on-answer-by-docweird-upgrade-to-16-04-failed).